# Can page text HTML structure big change affect on ranking?

Tags: wordpress, html, google-ranking

On my website I use Wordpress and WP Bakery Page Builder plugin to construct my pages. I want to switch from WPBakery PageBuilder to Gutenberg editor. This will change the text HTML structure. Will this (text HTML markup change) affect on my current rankings?

The main reason why I want to switch is the page speed.

Comment: Please stop undoing the moderator edit rollbacks. If you want to discuss our policy of removing website links from questions, in relation to this question or in general, you can make a discussion post on [meta]. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could affect your rankings, but if the content remains similar it is highly unlikely it will have any significant or long term effect.  Indeed, provided the content remains similar an increase in speed is likely to way more then offset any penalty the engine may apply.

Not related to your actual question, but I do wonder if switching to Gutenberg editor is actually going to help much (assuming you are trying to speed up the frontend).  I'd imagine that focusing on caching and things like lazy loading would have a  greater impact while still leaving a much easier-to-use backend.

Comment: Actually we do have all that. We even use LighSpeed server for caching. For user the website is super fast but for lighthouse for some reason it is not fast enough. WPbakery use too much useless .js code on the frontend and also PHP code on the backend (shortcode mapping takes time). On the other hand WPbakery HTML structure is much complicated on the front end. Too much div elements inside each div until you get to your simple span element. I want to have H2- P, span structure but not div->div->H2 and right after div->div->p... I assume this kind of bad HTML structure also affect on ranking.

Comment: I agree with this answer.  I've done enough redesigns that completely change the HTML structure of every page that I don't even worry about SEO during that process at this point.  Google cares about content.  HTML structure just doesn't matter for rankings.